# How to Handle Multiple drops for multiple components in drag and drop ;in one function or class?

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, listener

I have 5 floating buttons and i have 5 drop listeners one for each.
i am looking a way to implement all those 5 listeners in one class or function.Please help me how to do this.And i want all the drop eworking fine when combined in one class

here is the sample:

```
imageView1.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event)
    {
        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            {
                Log.e("DRaG1","START");
                return true;
            }
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            {
                Log.e("DRaG1","ENDED");
                return true;
            }
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            {
                Log.e("DRaG1","ETER");
                return true;
            }
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            {
                Log.e("DRaG1","EXIT");
                return true;
            }
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            {
                Log.e("DRaG1","DROP");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return  false;
    }
});





    imageView2.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event)
        {

            switch (event.getAction())
            {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                {
                    Log.e("DRaG2","START");
                    return true;
                }
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                {
                    Log.e("DRaG2","ENDED");
                    return true;
                }
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                {
                    Log.e("DRaG2","ETER");
                    return true;
                }
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                {
                    Log.e("DRaG2","EXIT");
                    return true;
                }
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                {
                    Log.e("DRaG2","DROP");
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: i did it by myself code is here

In Main Activity do this:
        imageView1.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
        imageView2.setOnDragListener(dragListener);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it by myself code is here
In Main Activity do this:
        `imageView1.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
        imageView2.setOnDragListener(dragListener);`

make a class for Drag Listenrer and call it:

```
public class DragListener extends Activity implements View.OnDragListener {

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event)
{
    final int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED: {
            Log.e("DRaG2", "START");
            return true;
        }
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED: {
            Log.e("DRaG2", "ENDED");
            return true;
        }
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED: {
            Log.e("DRaG2", "ETER");
            return true;
        }
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED: {
            Log.e("DRaG2", "EXIT");
            return true;
        }
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP: {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.imageView1)
            {
                ClipData.Item item = event.getClipData().getItemAt(0);
                Log.e("ITEM", item.getText().toString());
                Log.e("DRaG2", String.valueOf(v.getId()));


            }

            else if (v.getId() == R.id.imageView2)
            {
                ClipData.Item item = event.getClipData().getItemAt(0);
                Log.e("ITEM", item.getText().toString());
                Log.e("DRaG2", String.valueOf(v.getId()));
            }

            else if (v.getId() == R.id.imageView3)
            {
                ClipData.Item item = event.getClipData().getItemAt(0);
                Log.e("ITEM", item.getText().toString());
                Log.e("DRaG2", String.valueOf(v.getId()));
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}